# Upgrading current installation of python packages for all users

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I have installed several `python` (Python 3.6, Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 LTS) packages with `pip`, but this installation was made with `pip3 install package`, and so it is valid only for the users who installed them.
How can I upgrade this installation to all users, without doing a double installation?

I think that `sudo pip3 install package` installs a package for all users. Is it safe?

What do you recommend?

Comment: So, I have to reinstall the python packages with `sudo` or in a virtual environment and remove the local packages (to avoid double install of packages)...

Comment: You are not obliged but depending on your needs. Just be be adviced on when to escalate the access. So always go with virtualenv for development (confined) then local install for Desktop tools (user only), then global for daemons and services. Usually ordered this way in my experience.